# Can I assume NULL value in comparison as the false?

Tags: c, pointers, comparison, conditional-statements, null-pointer

I know that `NULL == (void *)0` but it is mentioned that it can be represented as a value which doesn't contain all zeros. What bothers me is if those pieces of code are equivalent for all `(any_type *)`:

```
any_type *val;

if (val) { ... };
```

and

```
if (val != NULL) { ... };
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. You can use the macro `NULL` in this way. It is a null pointer constant which is equal to `0`.

#### [comp.lang.c FAQ list · Question 5.3](http://c-faq.com/null/ptrtest.html):

> When C requires the Boolean value of an expression, a false value is inferred when the expression compares equal to zero, and a true value otherwise. That is, whenever one writes
>
> ```
> if(expr)
> ```
>
> where `expr` is any expression at all, the compiler essentially acts as if it had been written as
>
> ```
> if((expr) != 0)
> ```
>
> Substituting the trivial pointer expression `p` for `expr`, we have
>
> ```
> if(p)   is equivalent to    if(p != 0)
> ```
>
> and this is a comparison context, so the compiler can tell that the (implicit) `0` is actually a null pointer constant, and use the correct null pointer value. There is no trickery involved here; compilers do work this way, and generate identical code for both constructs. **The internal representation of a null pointer does not matter**.

---

> but it is mentioned that it can be represented as a value which doesn't contain all zeros.

Yes. True. But [representation doesn't matter](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=null) in this case:

> Whenever a programmer requests a null pointer, either by writing `0` or `NULL`, **it is the compiler's responsibility to generate whatever bit pattern the machine uses for that null pointer**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this broad and authoritative answer.